# error while extending an array: no operator found which takes

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to extend my array by one when i call the addBranch function, and then add the new Branch object to the that extended empty area, and I am trying to prevent my code from memory leak. I thought i was doing right but i am stuck with this function.

it gives me error "**binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Branch *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)**". I need some help here assigning the last element to a new Branch object that won't be deleted after extermination of function. I am just new to C++, so there might be some big mistakes. I am not allowed to use vectors etc.

```
  // ------- Adds a branch to system -------- //
    void BankingSystem::addBranch(const int id, const string name){
        if(isBranchExisting(id)){
            cout << "\n\tBranch " << id << " already exists. Please try it with another id number.";
        }
        else if(!isBranchExisting(id)){
            Branch* tempArray = new Branch[cntAccounts];
            for(int i = 0; i<cntAccounts; i++){
                tempArray[i] = allBranches[i];
            }

            delete[] allBranches;

            allBranches = new Branch[cntAccounts+1];
            for(int i = 0; i<cntAccounts; i++){
                allBranches[i] = tempArray[i];
            }
            allBranches[cntAccounts] = new Branch(id, name);  // error at this line

        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a coding tip: if you create `tempArray` with `new Branch[cntAccounts + 1]`, then you can copy all the elements from `allBranches` into `tempArray`, then add the new element to the end of `tempArray`, then `delete[] allBranches`, then `allBranches = tempArray`. That requires copying the elements only once instead of twice. Better, though, as others have said, to use `std::vector<Branch>`, which does all this for you.

Comment: do i have to delete `tempArray` after doing `allBranches = tempArray`?

Comment: No, don't delete it. It points to your current data, as does `allBranches`. If you delete it **both** pointers will point to garbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, you're trying to assign a pointer to an object. You (probably) want to assign an object instead:

```
allBranches[cntAccounts] = Branch(id, name); // no "new"
```

I would also suggest you use `std::vector<Branch>` rather than hand-forged arrays. This will fix the memory leak from forgetting to delete `tempArray`, or from something throwing an exception if you do add the missing `delete[]`.

Also, if you do use `vector`, then the whole dance can be replaced with

```
allBranches.push_back(Branch(id, name));
```

Comment: Then here is my question: does this object gets deleted after the execution of function? I watched many videos about memory management but I am still incompetent about it.

Additionally, i would like to use them but as i stated in my question, we are not allowed to that.

Comment: @BurakÖzmen: Conceptually it creates a temporary object, moves or copies it into the array, then destroys the temporary; the copy in the array remains as long as the array does. (In practice, the copy or move will be avoided by the "copy elision" optimisation).

Comment: @BurakÖzmen: The best approach to memory management is not to manage it yourself. Use containers and smart pointers to do it for you. If you really want to do it yourself, then it's simple: everything you create with `new`/`new` must be destroyed with `delete`/`delete[]`. Everything created without `new` will be destroyed automatically.

Comment: (Too late to fix the typo - that should read "... create with `new`/`new[]` ...")